# JQuery Post Form in ASP.NET MVC 3.0 FormCollection

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, forms

I try to submit a form in Jquery to an Action method in a Controller.
To do so I serialize my form and use the get method. In the controller I receive my form as a string like param1=1&param2=2....
Is there a way to retrieve directly a FormCollection in my Action Method instead of the string. As my form has many checkboxes it will be easier for me to have it in formCollection.

Here is my Jquery:

```
 var form = $("#CheckForm");
                    var formCollection = form.serialize();
                    $.post('@Url.Action("CheckSelection")', { clientId: clientId, policyId: policyId, countryCode: country, month: monthtoken[0] + '*' + monthtoken[1], formCollection: formCollection }, function () {
                        alert("formSubmit");
                    });
```

Here my form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("CheckSelection", "Check", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "CheckForm" }))
{        
<fieldset>
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.CheckBox("CodeExist",true)
    @Html.Label("Check Code Existence")
</div>
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.CheckBox("Mandatory",true)
    @Html.Label("Check Code Reccurence")
</div>
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.CheckBox("Reccurence",true)
    @Html.Label("Check Mandatory Code")
</div>
}
```

Here is my Action Method:

```
 [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult CheckSelection(string clientId, string policyId, string countryCode, string month, FormCollection formCollection){}
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var form = $("#CheckForm");
var formCollection = form.serialize();
$.post('@Url.Action("CheckSelection")', formCollection , function (data) {
    alert(data); //will alert form submitted
});
```

and the controller will look like

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult CheckSelection(FormCollection collection){
    return Content("form submitted");
}
```

for details of the FormCollection class follow this [*link*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.formcollection.aspx)

Comment: Thanks it's working. I assumed I was mixed GET & POST parameter. So if I want to retrieve the other parameter I have to create hidden field in the form right?

Comment: what other parameter all the form values will be available in the form collection if you want some additional values yes you can make a hidden field also you are using mvc3.net start looking into "strongly typed" views ...

Comment: It is a common practice for us to post forms like this i.e. ajax way. I recommend you to study Model Binding in MVC. You will rarely need FormCollection since you can directly get a prepared Model object. Let me know if you need further clarification on this.

Answer (score 1):

So, serializing the form works great for passing all of the form values to the action result, but it then becomes a pain to work with the serialized URL string, especially when I was already using the name/value combination of the FormCollection already. I just wanted to switch the function over to be posted through jQuery instead of a normal form submit.  To that end, I wrote a helper function that converts that serialized form into a normal form collection, just as if the form was submitted normally.

Enjoy.

```
private FormCollection DeSerialize(FormCollection form)
{
  FormCollection collection = new FormCollection();
  //un-encode, and add spaces back in
  string querystring = Uri.UnescapeDataString(form[0]).Replace("+", " ");
  var split = querystring.Split(new [] {'&'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
  Dictionary<string, string> items = new Dictionary<string, string>();      
  foreach (string s in split)
  {        
    string text = s.Substring(0, s.IndexOf("="));
    string value = s.Substring(s.IndexOf("=")+1);

    if (items.Keys.Contains(text))
      items[text] = items[text] + "," + value;
    else
      items.Add(text, value);
  }
  foreach (var i in items)
  {
    collection.Add(i.Key, i.Value);
  }            
  return collection;
}
```

Comment: what would you do if u have ````&```` in your response?

Comment: If you have an '&' in your input; it will be URL encoded, so don't need to worry about that.

Answer (score 0):

I modified the method provided by @Aaron McCoy above to handle '&' in input:

```
private FormCollection DeSerialize(string val)
{
FormCollection collection = new FormCollection();
//un-encode, and add spaces back in
var split = val.Split(new[] { '&' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
Dictionary<string, string> items = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach (string s in split)
{
var v = Uri.UnescapeDataString(s).Replace("+", " ");
string text = v.Substring(0, v.IndexOf("="));
string value = v.Substring(v.IndexOf("=") + 1);

if (items.Keys.Contains(text))
items[text] = items[text] + "," + value;
else
items.Add(text, value);
}
foreach (var i in items)
{
collection.Add(i.Key, i.Value);
}
return collection;
}
```

Hope that helps!